# Inconsistent Lighting Across Objects

Tags: shaders, lighting

Sort of odd lighting here..

Not sure what is causing this weird lighting.  My workflow is to copy the edge of the door frame, duplicate, separate it to a new object, and translate in the edges a bit to get a bit of a panel gap. The geometry is therefore exactly the same, I checked my shade flat/smooth areas and they are the same. Any ideas what causes this weird lighting?

[image]

Comment: It is not that easy to understand what weird part you are referring to  ... Anyway try to check Face Normal Orientation ...

Comment: Try to Clear Custom Normal Data in the Mesh Properties

Comment: Reseting the normal vectors worked. Thanks for the idea!